# help with regex sentence

Tags: c#, regex

how to do this in regex

`C*.C*`  (start with C .... have dot and start with C)

`33*.33` (start with 33.... have dot and 33)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
C.*\.C.*
```

should do it. Don't forget to escape the backslash or use a literal string if you're using .NET.

Answer (score 2):

```
C.*\.C.*

33.*\.33
```

you have to use the backslash to escape the `.`

Comment: Note that `C*\.C*` matches a single DOT as well: which does not start with a `C`.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(C|33)+\.(C|33)+$
```

Hope this should do the trick